# My error page will not load on S3, it says access denied.. How do I fix this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hosting a static website on s3. Every page is working except for my error page. Do I need to redirect unknown links to my error page? I haven't seen anything on this.
Everything that I've seen/read says to add the error.html file to the S3 and then add it to the error document section.

My bucket is public and I have my json document added as well.

Policy i'm using-

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*************/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

[Error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ozNR.png)

Comment: Hi , is your error.html the same name as the static website hosting error document in the s3 bucket ?

Comment: Yes. They are both error.html

Comment: And the  example.com is working but the example.com/pathdoesntexist  you get access denied ?

Comment: yeah, everything else is working except for the error.html

http://karma-environmental-services.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: Could it be a caching issue? The error.html page loads for me.

Comment: hmmmm, really? I cleared my cache and I'm still getting the same issue.. How are you getting to it? i'm trying to add a / and random characters after to see if it will redirect to the page and that is how i'm getting the access denied page

Comment: Yes, so when I do a /error.html at the end it does work for me. So it is accessible to the public.

Answer (score 0):

I tried http://karma-environmental-services.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test
[image]

It seems that your browser was cached.

Comment: my browser WAS cached! Thanks so much.

Comment: You can close the question by pressing the check in the answer that helped you. :)